# Property appears to be self initializing when running in unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a strange issue, that makes no sense. It appears that one of my variables that store a custom class is self initializing when it should be staying null. I've deleted 99% of the code in the two class files involved and simplified the remaining to its minimum while debugging, yet it still occurs.

The code is in question is designed to [ExecuteInEditMode] in the background in Unity while the designer does their thing and not in play.

1. On the first tick, ownedData evaluates as expected (null).
2. On the second tick, ownedData is evaluating as if an object was assigned even though I ensure that canPrepare is never set to true. (Its internal properties are still null though)

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData {
    public byte[] id { get; private set; } = null;

    public MyData(byte[] id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

#if (UNITY_EDITOR)
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
#endif
public class Owner : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool canPrepare = false; //Made private to ensure nothing external can set this to true
    private MyData ownedData = null;

#if (UNITY_EDITOR)
    private float _editorTime;
    public void Awake() {
        EditorApplication.update += EditorDataEval;
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        EditorApplication.update -= EditorDataEval;
    }

    private void EditorDataEval() {
        if (Application.isPlaying) { return; }

        if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - _editorTime >= 1f) {//Tick once per #f seconds
            _editorTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

            if (ownedData == null) {
                if (canPrepare) {
                    ownedData = new MyData(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
                }
                return;
            } else {
                //Should never be called as canPrepare is not set
                Debug.Log("Data id: "+ ownedData.id);
            }
        }
    }
#endif

//TOOD: Add class methods back in once bug resolved.
}
```

I'm starting to theorize that `Unity` is in the background auto initializing the variable in order to show it in the editor...

Comment: "I'm starting to theorize that unity is in the background auto initializing the variable in order to show it in the editor..." Why would it want to show it in the editor when it's private to the class (and not using SerializeField)?

Comment: @Phillipp Its a theory, but even though it's not visible in the inspector, there's still a '<ownedData>k__Backing Field' that's shown when you change the inspector tab from normal to debug.

Comment: What happens if you remove `private MyData ownedData = null;` (and all connected code), save the scene, then bring it back -- does that clear Unity's magic cache of it?

Comment: did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and set some breakpoints e.g. at the line `ownedData = new MyData(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());` ? Also did you enter the [**`Debug` mode**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html) in the Inspector? This reveals all private fields of serializable types read-only .. In this case Unity might auto initialize the field since its type is `[Serializable]`!

Comment: @derHugo I tried both of those, that's what gave me the borderline conspiracy theory about the auto initilization.

Answer (score 2):

By default this should and does not happen since your field is not `public` and not `[SerializeField]`.

I guess you once entered the [**Debug** mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html) in the Inspector:

[image]

In this case the Unity Inspector will automatically instantiate the field because its type is `[Serializable]`! Later it stays instantiated until the scene is re-loaded even if you already left the Debug mode.

As you can see not even <kbd>Reset</kbd> does help - I can only guess but I think Unity only resets the serialized Inspector fields here.

A really quick fix would be to simply enter and exit PlayMode once. The scene and thereby your component is reloaded and the field reset to `null`.

Another option would be to implement the [`Reset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html) method and actually do it there

```
private void Reset()
{
    ownedData = null;
}
```

Now if you try it again and hit <kbd>Reset</kbd> in the contextMenu you can see that the output is stopped since the field is reset to `null`.

[image]